# Is travelling allowed in Uttarakhand without E-pass?

Tags: trains, india, health, domestic-travel, solo-travel

Looking for a small vacation since it's been a long time hiding inside home. If anyone could share the exact travelling guidelines for Uttarakhand it will be great.

- Is e-pass required for the travel?
- Does the state govt. need medical certificates?
- Is there any requirement for being quarantined after or during the travel time?